# If $f$ is an $L_1$ function, how to prove this integration identity by substitution?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-\frac{1}{x})\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

I tried to do substitution like $t=x-1/x$, but could not get the result. Then I tried to use characteristic function to solve this, but stucked. I am wondering if this can be solved by convolution approximation?

Comment: You'll find that you get a lot more help and fewer down votes if you indicate that you've attempted to do the problem yourself.  What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I tried to do substitution like t=x-1/x, but could not get the result. Then I tried to use characteristic function to solve this, but stucked. I am wondering if this can be solved by convolution approximation?

Comment: Whatever you have tried, you should put it into your question, so that others know the background of you.

Comment: You may ask yourself why the above is true for functions like $\chi_{[a,b]}$. Depending on your background, solving this case is already sufficient.

Comment: Split it at $0$ and try. I know that the question $x+1/x$ has been asked before.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x-\frac{1}{x}=t$.

For $x>0$ we have $x=\frac{1}{2}(t+\sqrt{4+t^2})$ and 
$$dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t^2}}\right)dt,$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\left(1+\frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t^2}}\right)dt.
\end{aligned}$$
On the other hand for $x<0$, $x-\frac{1}{x}$ implies $x=\frac{1}{2}(t-\sqrt{4+t^2})$ and 
$$dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t^2}}\right)dt,$$
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^0 f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\left(1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t^2}}\right)dt.
\end{aligned}$$
Thus
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)dt.$$

Comment: I see, thanks very much. I do like this, but make the integration range of t as $[0, +\infinity)$. That’s why I obtain the wrong result. Thanks very much.