# Integral identity using the transformation formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable. I want to show that
$$ \int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda(x).$$
I tried to use the transformation formula, but I did not get the identity. I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: λ(x) is any arbitrary function of x or do you want to prove that there exists such function λ(x) for which this is true?

Comment: $\lambda$ means the Lebesgue measure in this context.

Comment: If $d\lambda(x)$ simply stands for the usual Lebesgue measure, this is an instance of the Glasser master theorem, known as the Cauchy-Schlomilch substitution: https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2445

Comment: Separate the RHS into $\int_{0}^{+\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{0}$. Then change variable $y=x-1/x$ in the two integrals. You get two integrals from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Sum them. The derivative appearing in the change of variable add up to $1$.

Comment: Isn't the derivate $1 + \frac{1}{x^2}$? Can you see my mistake?

Comment: When you make the change of variable $y=x-1/x$ the derivative appearing comes from $dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}dy$. It is the derivative of the inverse of $x-1/x$. You will need to be careful, watching out for the signs, when you make the change of variable in each of the integral.

Comment: Okay, it seems like that I got another formula for the transformation of integrals. The theorem I have learned was:

Comment: Okay, it seems like that I got another formula for the transformation of integrals. The theorem I have learned was:

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ an open set and $\Phi \longrightarrow \Phi(\Omega)$ a diffeomorphism. This implies

$$\int_{\Phi(\Omega)} f(y) \, \mathrm{d}y = \int_{\Omega} f(\Omega(x)) |\text{det}(D \Phi(x)) | \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

Comment: So my idea was that $\Phi_{>0}: \mathbb{R}_{>0} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x - 1/x$, $\Phi_{<0}: \mathbb{R}_{<0} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x - 1/x$ are diffeomorphisms both with derivative $1 + 1/x^2$. So I got

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1/2 \left( \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x +  \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \right)$$ $$= 1/2 \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}_{>0}} f(x) (x +1/x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x +  \int_{\mathbb{R}_{<0}} f(x) (x +1/x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x \right) = 1/2 \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) (x +1/x^2) \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Upon quick calculations (please check and get back to me) I think the inequality is false. Let $f:=\chi_{[0,1]},\,$ the characteristic function of the interval $[0,1]$. Then $f$ is obviously integrable with $\int f =1$ (assuming your measure $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure). Quick calculations show $f(x-1/x)=\chi_{[1,\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}]\cup [-\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2},-1]}$ and $\int f(x-1/x)=\sqrt{5}-2\neq 1$.

Comment: That is actually equal to 1

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681901/if-f-is-an-l-1-function-how-to-prove-this-integration-identity-by-substitut#comment5538748_2681901

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Define$$
g_1(x) = x - \frac{1}{x}\ (x < 0), \quad g_2(x) = x - \frac{1}{x}\ (x > 0),$$
then$$
h_1(y) = g_1^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{2} (y - \sqrt{\smash[b]{y^2 + 4}}),\quad h_2(y) = g_2^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{2} (y + \sqrt{\smash[b]{y^2 + 4}}). \quad \forall y \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Therefore for integrable $f$,\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\left( x - \frac{1}{x} \right) \,\d x &= \int_{(-\infty, 0)} f(g_1(x)) \,\d x + \int_{(0, +\infty)} f(g_2(x)) \,\d x\\
&= \int_{g_1((-\infty, 0))} f(u) |h_1'(u)| \,\d u + \int_{g_2((0, +\infty))} f(u) |h_2'(u)| \,\d u\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u) · \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 - \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 + 4}} \right) \,\d u + \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u) · \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2 + 4}} \right) \,\d u\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u) \,\d u.
\end{align*}